# How do I mirror modifier in the same place?

Tags: rendering, mirror-modifier

I am trying to use the *Mirror Modifier*, but the mirrored object is not appearing on its original axis.

What would be the reason and solution?

[image: Mirror modifier mirrors at the wrong place]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: Switch to Object Mode > <kbd>RightClick</kbd> > Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor

[Mirror Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html) use Origin Point as center point to mirroring. In your case  your Origin Point was up there. So set Origin Point to 3D Cursor will solve your problem.[image: Origin Point]*Origin Point*

You can also use the other object's Origin Point as center point by Mirror Object in Mirror Modifier options.[image: Use Sphere as Mirror Object]*Use Sphere as Mirror Object*

In case you want to set 3D Cursor to World Origin.
<kbd>RightClick</kbd> > Snap > Cursor to World Origin

Or move Origin Point to the center of model.
<kbd>RightClick</kbd> > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry

Comment: thank you @Tergturry